# Set Thumbnail to file - c#

Tags: c#, thumbnails

I have created a new file extension called (.mrs) .

And now I want to set Thumbnail to the .mrs file(s) which Windows Explorer can display it.

(Like Adobe Reader file (.pdf) << that file have a Thumbnail referred to book cover)

How can I do that programmatically?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144118(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this tutorial. There is a quick example of the thumbnail image handler code sample.

Writing Windows Shell Extension with .NET 4 - Part 3

http://geekswithblogs.net/Jialiang/archive/2010/11/08/writing-windows-shell-extension-with-.net-4---part-3.aspx